# How to test app on Android device

Tags: android

I have my app on eclipse and I'd like to test it on Nexus S. I use Ubuntu 10.04 and Eclipse Helios. I'm searching for it on web but cant find it. If someone knows how to launch the app on Nexus S tell me detailed please. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the SDK documentation on this topic? http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: yeah, I've created the file with this code SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666" what should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I right clicked on the project and selected Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package and then I choosed the location of the .apk package. And then in the terminal I typed ./adb install .

---

Also there is another way. The better way from my point of view.

Via Terminal or Command Prompt, access the platform-tools directory.

With your phone set to usb debug mode and disconnected from PC usb, type in terminal or command prompt:

**windows:** adb kill-server

**linux**: ./adb kill-server

and then

**windows:** adb start-server

**linux**: ./adb start-server

now type this for check if it worked, it should show the device ID

**windows:** adb devices

**linux**: ./adb devices

Now, just go to eclipse and set the IDE to run the app on the device and run it.

---

**UPDATE**

**As the API has changed in the earliest versions, I advise you to follow the API documentation.**

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html#RunningOnDeviceEclipse

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 0):

[All purpose explanation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

- Always do this

  1. On your phone: settings >> applications >> unknown sources = true
  2. On your phone: settings >> applications >> development >> usb debugging = true

     - If you are on a mac that should be it, if you are on windows you [might also need this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) and if you are on unix you might also need some sort of udev rules, which I do not understand but which are to a certain extent also explained [here again...](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)